# 401 Unauthorised When Switching To Live

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, paypal

I am trying to use PayPal to authorise web payments. I have successfully upgraded my account to Web Payments Pro, and have built a solution which worked fine in sandbox to handle credit card payments.

However, now that I am trying to switch to live mode, I am receiving error 401 Unauthorised.

What am I doing wrong?

I am using OAuth as follows:

```
private OAuthTokenCredential ApiAccessToken
    {
        get
        {
            if (this._authToken != null)
            {
                return this._authToken;
            }

            var clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["clientId"];
            var secretToken = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["secretToken"];
            var config = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "mode", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PayPalMode"] } };

            this._authToken = new OAuthTokenCredential(clientId, secretToken, config);

            return this._authToken;
        }
    }
```

I have switched mode to "live", and verified the clientId and secret tokens. I have even deleted the app and re-created it. Still the error

Comment: Never used paypal but usually clients like that only work on the specific domain you registered them to. Did paypal have this option when creating the client id and secret token?

Answer (score 1):

Typically, that error means there is something wrong with your client id and secret, or you may be setting the environment to sandbox in your apiContext. You also need to be approved for REST API direct credit card payments. You can do this in sandbox without approval, but switching to live you do need to be approved.

Log in to developer.paypal.com > Dashboard > My account and check under the "Live" column. If you see the "Enable" link, click it and it will submit your application for approval.

Answer (score 1):

i was facing same issue i solved it by changing

```
name="mode" value="sandbox"
```

to

```
name="mode" value="live"
```

in web.config in .net mvc

Answer (score 0):

To take your application live:

1. Ensure your application adheres to the PayPal Application Policies
   and Guidelines.
2. Update the Sandbox API credentials in your PayPal calls to those
   assigned to a live PayPal account.
3. Update your PayPal endpoints from the Sandbox to the PayPal production servers
4. Register your application with PayPal.
5. If your application makes use of Adaptive operations, obtain a live
   AppID.
6. Go Live !

More details about it, check Paypal https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/lifecycle/goingLive/